# ¿ Como extraer el tipo de un objeto en typescript?

Tags: typescript

Si pongo por ejemplo:

```
const obj = {
  a: 1,
  b: 'string'
};
```

Si quiero usar ese objeto en una función tengo que poner así:

```
function (obj: { a: number; b: string; }): number {
return obj.a;
}
```

---

¿Cómo puedo guardar ese tipo autogenerado?

Sería algo como así:

```
const obj: set objType = {
  a: 1,
  b: 'string'
};

function (obj: objType): number {
return obj.a;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías usar el operador `typeof` de **Typescript**

**Referencia**:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html

finalmente tu función quedaría así:

```js
const obj = {
    a: 1,
    b: 'string'
};

function myFunction(myObj: typeof obj): number {
    return myObj.a;
}
```

La ventaja que tiene esto sobre el uso de **interfaces** es que el en cuanto agregues, modifiques o elimines algún elemento de `obj` automáticamente los tipos se van a actualizar.

---

Para ver el ejemplo en Typescript playground puedes ingresar acá:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=8&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArGBeGBvAsAKBnmAhgFwwCMANDvjPCQOTQBOAlmAOZ04C+A3DjgDMArmGBRm4GAFsAngDERYiWAAUsgPJISUGQAcApiAFwkAShJghU+PsYYq+RvqhDGYaTM2IAdAT7YuIA

Comment: Gracias, es lo que buscaba.